# Can GridSearchCV use predict_proba when using a custom score function?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to use a custom scoring function that calculates multi-class log loss with the ground truth and predict_proba y array. Is there a way to make GridSearchCV use this scoring function?

```
def multiclass_log_loss(y_true, y_pred):
Parameters
----------
y_true : array, shape = [n_samples]
        true class, intergers in [0, n_classes - 1)
y_pred : array, shape = [n_samples, n_classes]

Returns
-------
loss : float
"""
eps=1e-15
predictions = np.clip(y_pred, eps, 1 - eps)

# normalize row sums to 1
predictions /= predictions.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]

actual = np.zeros(y_pred.shape)
n_samples = actual.shape[0]
actual[np.arange(n_samples), y_true.astype(int)] = 1
vectsum = np.sum(actual * np.log(predictions))
loss = -1.0 / n_samples * vectsum
return loss
```

I see that there are multiple options, score_func, loss_func and make_scorer. I tried using make_scorer with greater_is_better=False and also tried the loss_func parameter but it seems to still use the .predict method. How can I get around this problem?

UPDATE - if I set needs_threshold=True I get a multi-class error. Am I correct to understand multi-class is not supported in this case? If yes, can someone suggest a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: You can simply use ``scoring="log_loss"`` and don't need to bother with all this. Still, multiclass should be supported here.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I didn't see log_loss as a scoring option in the docs so didn't think it was built in. But it's great to know! Although I couldn't get multiclass to work with the custom function. Do we turn on predict_proba by saying need_threshold=true when making the scorer?

Comment: Yes. A list of all built-in loss functions is here: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values

Comment: It's not very prominent, we should make this list more visible ....

Comment: Agree. Section 3.5 actually lists the common options. Log loss and a few others could be moved up from the code block to the list since they're pretty standard. btw the documentation is pretty great.

Answer (score 1):

The top answer to  this question:
[Pass estimator to custom score function via sklearn.metrics.make_scorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064637/pass-estimator-to-custom-score-function-via-sklearn-metrics-make-scorer)

might have what you need. One can define a scorer that takes as arguments a classifier `clf`, feature array `X`, and targets `y_true`, and feed the result of the `clf.predict_proba()` method to a scoring function that  returns the error. As a hint, for binary classification, you probably need to use

`clf.predict_proba(X)[:,1]`

This worked for my needs (a normalized Gini score). For some reason, I couldn't get sklearn's `metrics.make_scorer` to work with my custom function that needs probabilities.