# Pass estimator to custom score function via sklearn.metrics.make_scorer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'd like to make a custom scoring function involving classification probabilities as follows:

```
def custom_score(y_true, y_pred_proba):
    error = ...
    return error

my_scorer = make_scorer(custom_score, needs_proba=True)

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=KNeighborsClassifier(),
                  param_grid=[{'n_neighbors': [6]}],
                  cv=5,
                  scoring=my_scorer)
```

Is there any way to pass the estimator, as fit by GridSearch with the given data and parameters, to my custom scoring function? Then I could interpret the probabilities using `estimator.classes_`

For example:

```
def custom_score(y_true, y_pred_proba, clf):
    class_labels = clf.classes_
    error = ...
    return error
```

Answer (score 14):

There is an alternative way to make a scorer [mentioned in the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object). Using this method I can do the following:

```
def my_scorer(clf, X, y_true):
    class_labels = clf.classes_
    y_pred_proba = clf.predict_proba(X)
    error = ...
    return error

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=KNeighborsClassifier(),
                  param_grid=[{'n_neighbors': [6]}],
                  cv=5,
                  scoring=my_scorer)
```

This avoids the use of `sklearn.metrics.make_scorer`.

Comment: You can not use `classes_` attribute of `clf` in my_scorer because at the time of the execution of `my_scorer` function, the classifier isn't fit yet.

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is when you have multiple scorers you run predict_proba once per scorer

Comment: How does gridsearch use the best params for my_scorer function like lower the error is better or higher

Answer (score 4):

According to [make_scorer docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer), it receives ****kwargs : additional arguments** as additional parameters to be passed to score_func.

So you can just write your score function as:

```
def custom_score(y_true, y_pred_proba, clf):
    class_labels = clf.classes_
    error = ...
    return error
```

Then use make_scorer as:

```
my_scorer = make_scorer(custom_score, needs_proba=True, clf=clf_you_want)
```

The benefit of this method is you can pass any other param to your score function easily.